# How to filter using OR expression in Dynamics NAV web service?

Tags: filter, navision, dynamics-nav

I need some help in filtering keyword in two different field using OR expression. See example below.

I need to search John to both FirstName and ShortName field from NAV using OR.

```
CustomerInterface.ClientInterface_Filter[] filters =
{
new CustomerInterface.CustomerInterface_Filter(),
new CustomerInterface.CustomerInterface_Filter(),
};

filters[0].Field = CustomerInterface.CustomerInterface_Fields.FirstName;
filters[0].Criteria = "John";

filters[0].Field = CustomerInterface.CustomerInterface_Fields.ShortName;
filters[0].Criteria = "John";

CustomerInterface.CustomerInterface[] response = service.ReadMultiple(filters.ToArray(), null, 0);
```

How do I filter it? Thanks.

Comment: In Nav you can’t set OR-filter on two fields. So don’t think you can do it via web service other than querying twice.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use the construct FILTERGROUP(-1) in NAV code - it will work effectively as OR clause.

```
SearchString := 'John';
FILTERGROUP(-1);
SETFILTER("First Name", SearchString);
SETFILTER("Short Name", SearchString);
IF FINDSET THEN REPEAT
  ...
UNTIL NEXT = 0;
FILTERGROUP(0);
```

It is actualy a mechanism behind search box feature in NAV web client list pages.

So you may create a custom codeunit function in NAV to filter out and return the results. Not sure if it is possible to do the same from web service consumer side.

More details in this blog post:
https://dynamicsuser.net/nav/b/vanvugt/posts/filtergroup-1

Filter group -1 is merely mentioned in MSDN documentation but without any details:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics-nav/filtergroup-function--record-